# How to make ingress use my TLS Certificate in Microk8s

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, microk8s

I have the following Ingress configuration:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1        
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: http-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example-adress.com
    http:
      paths:
        - path: /apple
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
                name: apple-service
                port: 
                  number: 80
        - path: /banana
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
                name: banana-service
                port: 
                  number: 80
  tls: 
    - hosts: 
        - example-adress.com
      secretName: testsecret-tls
```

And i also created the Secret:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: testsecret-tls
  namespace: default
data:
  tls.crt: path to .crt
  tls.key: Zpath to .key
type: kubernetes.io/tls
```

But when i connect to one of my services and check the certificate it says that it uses a cert created by Kubernetes Ingress Controller Fake certificate.
When i run microk8s kubectl describe ingress i get the following output:

```
Name:             http-ingress
Namespace:        default
Address:          127.0.0.1
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>)
TLS:
 testsecret-tls terminates example-adress.com
Rules:
 Host               Path  Backends
 ----               ----  --------
 example-adress.com
                    /apple    apple-service:80 (10.1.55.17:5678)
                    /banana   banana-service:80 (10.1.55.10:5678)
Annotations:         <none>
Events:
 Type    Reason  Age                From                      Message
 ----    ------  ----               ----                      -------
 Normal  CREATE  28m                nginx-ingress-controller  Ingress default/http-ingress
 Normal  UPDATE  20m (x2 over 28m)  nginx-ingress-controller  Ingress default/http-ingress
```

What do i need to change to make my Ingress use my Cert instead of generating a new one everytime?

Comment: Have you tried adding `tls.crt` and `tls.key` as base64 encrypted values? It seems like k8s doesn't get paths [Reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#tls-secrets)
Also you can create a secret using following command:
`kubectl create secret tls testsecret-tls --cert=tls.cert --key=tls.key`

Comment: Thank you moonkotte. I tried it out and both of your suggestions work it seems like i really had to add the encrypted values instead of the path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting this out of comment as it works.

Based on your tls secret yaml, you tried to add certificate and private key using paths, which is not supported currently ([reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#tls-secrets))
Fragment from reference:

> When using this type of Secret, the `tls.key` and the `tls.crt` key must be provided in the `data` (or `stringData`) field of the Secret configuration, although the API server doesn't actually validate the values for each key.

Therefore there are two suggestions how to move forward:

- Add base64 encrypted values for key and certificate to tls secret
- Allow kubernetes do it for you with the following command:
  `kubectl create secret tls testsecret-tls --cert=tls.cert --key=tls.key`